# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ApplicationPackageManager$ResourceName

Tags: facebook-login

We are using Facebook login "com.facebook.android:facebook-login:${"5.15.1"}.. This crash we got for random user on crashlytcis, not able to reproduce straightforward. Can you please help us solve this

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ApplicationPackageManager$ResourceName cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]
at android.util.ArrayMap.allocArrays(ArrayMap.java:187)
at android.util.ArrayMap.put(ArrayMap.java:459)
at android.os.BaseBundle.putString(BaseBundle.java:430)
at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.getAppSettingsQueryResponse(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:368)
at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.access$100(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:62)
at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager$1.run(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:179)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your affected user base is using Android 5.

There's a related issue in the Google Issue Tracker, basically explaining that this is due to a concurrency problem.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37114373

So, nothing to fix if your crashes are only happening on Android Lollipop devices.